# EF Core Azure Cosmos DB Provider vs Cosmos LINQ to SQL translation

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to fetch data from a Cosmos DB by enabling server-side pagination. I have two options:

1. Using EF Core Azure Cosmos DB Provider

   `var query = DbContext.Order.AsQueryable();`
2. Using Azure Cosmos LINQ to SQL translation

   `var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Order>(allowSynchronousQueryExecution: true);`

I'm going to fetch data by using `Skip` and `Take`

```
var data = query.Skip(args.Skip).Take(args.Take).ToList();
```

what could be the better solution?

Comment: You gonna pay for that..... The best solution you hit your partition key. If you dont its gonna be expensive.

Comment: I’m going to use partition key with where clause on both options.

Comment: Then its not about better solution underline will be same thing. So use what you comfortable with

Answer (score 0):

**Entity Framework Provider**

The Cosmos DB provider will assist in removing a lot of the source code that we must implement when using the SDK.

The provider will allow us to use the Entity Framework and all its benefits, as well as Cosmos DB for persistence.

**Pagination of EF**

Pagination refers to retrieving results in pages, rather than all at once; this is typically done for large resultsets, where a us er interface is shown that allows the user to navigate to the next or previous page of the results, Please refer in this document

[Pagination - EF Core | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/pagination)

**Pagination Linq to sql**

The Azure Cosmos DB query provider converts a LINQ query into an Azure Cosmos DB SQL query using best effort. Use the ToString() method on the generated IQueryableobject to get the SQL query that was translated from LINQ.

[LINQ to SQL translation in Azure Cosmos DB | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/linq-to-sql)

LINQ Take() function will limit how many items are taken. The Skip() function will ignore the first n items. Something like this might work:

myDataSource.Skip(pageSize * curPage).Take(pageSize)

**Solution:**

You can use Cosmonaut, which supports skip-take pagination, with the. Method With Pagination (pageNum, pageSize). It accomplishes this by scrolling through the results until you reach the page, but there are ways to improve performance.

#More information about pagination and pagination recommendations can be found here posted by Nick

[Elfocrash/Cosmonaut:  A supercharged Azure CosmosDB .NET SDK with ORM support (github.com)](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#pagination)